# Jquery events and objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, jquery-events

I'm trying to do this:

```
var foo = new Foo();
foo.setEvents( foo );
```

Code of foo:

```
function Foo()
{
   this.id = getId(); //this works successfully, each instance of foo gets
                          //assigned a new auto incrementing id e.g 1, 2, 3, etc

   this.setEvents = function( that ) 
   {
      $("#myButton").click( that.bar );
   }

   this.bar = function()
   {
      alert(this.id);
   }
}
```

Whenever I run this code and click on my button, I get an alert saying 'undefined'

How can I preserve the state of the object whose method I want to run when the event is triggered?

Comment: Your handle and avatar make me want to downvote this question.

Comment: [It works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/DAPYt/).

Comment: @alex he was expecting to get the id of the object and not the button.

Comment: @kingjiv: Oh, I see :) I made an answer.

Comment: @KirkWoll: Let's see if we can upvote him to 30,000? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this refers to something different in jQuerys scope...

```
function Foo()
{
   obj=this;
   this.id = 1; //this works successfully, each instance of foo gets
                          //assigned a new auto incrementing id e.g 1, 2, 3, etc

   this.setEvents = function( that ) 
   {
      $("#myButton").click( that.bar );
   }

   this.bar = function()
   {
      console.log(obj)
   }
}
var foo = new Foo();
foo.setEvents( foo );
```

Answer (score 1):

When that function is called, `this` points to the native DOM element that handled the event.

You need a reference to the object itself that can be resolved in the scope of that function.

A common method of doing this is with `var that = this`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/6AgWv/).